# How can I replace a box of text with beamer?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I currently have this piece of text for a quiz:

```
\begin{frame}{Quiz}
    \begin{block}{Frage}
        With generics the compiler has more information about the 
        types of the objects, so explicit casts don't have to be used 
        and the compiler can produce type safe code.

        What implications have the generics for the runtime 
        performance of the  program which uses them?
    \end{block}

    \only<1>{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item With the generics the compiler can optimize the code for 
              used types. This and the omission of the casts are the 
              reasons why the code compiled with the generics is 
              \textbf{quicker} than the one compiled without.
        \item The usage of generics has \textbf{no implications} for 
              the runtime performance of the compiled programs.
        \item The improved flexibility and type safety means that the 
              compiler has to generate concrete implementation from 
              the generic template for each used type. This means 
              that applications start \textbf{a bit slower}.
    \end{itemize}}
    \only<2>{
        The Java Virtual Machine and the copiled byte code are Generics 
        agnostic. The comiled byte code does not differ from byte code 
        compiled from sources which don't use the generics.
        So using the generics has \textbf{no impact} on the runtime 
        performance of compiled Java code.
    }
\end{frame}
```

I would like to present the question with the different possibilities to answer and on the next slides the different possibilities to answer should disappear, the rest should not move and the correct answer with an explanation should appear.

The current solution is not optimal, as the question moves. I've also tried visible instead of only, but with this solution the explanation doesn't appear at all.

(I know I could manually fix the "moving question problem" by adding space, but I don't want to do this for all slides.)

Comment: Did you try `uncover<2>`?

Comment: If I use uncover, the answer will be shown before I reveal it. I don't want my students simply to read the answer...

Comment: I know that there are 2 similar commands and one of them save space for the next one. Are you using transparency 100% to completely hide the items?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `\only` by `\onslide`?

Comment: The problem here is that the contents is to much and does not fit only on a single slide. See here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/38omxe8agtgxy14/bla.pdf

Comment: @Sigur: With my the theme of my university, it fits on a single slide.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: I've just tried it, but with `\onslide`, the list doesn't completely disappear. It only gets grayed out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may try the `overprint` environment (chap. 9.5, beamer user guide).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Quiz}
    \begin{block}{Frage}
        With generics the compiler has more information about the 
        types of the objects, so explicit casts don't have to be used 
        and the compiler can produce type safe code.

        What implications have the generics for the runtime 
        performance of the  program which uses them?
    \end{block}

    \begin{overprint}
      \onslide<1>
      \begin{itemize}
      \item With the generics the compiler can optimize the code for 
        used types. This and the omission of the casts are the 
        reasons why the code compiled with the generics is 
        \textbf{quicker} than the one compiled without.
      \item The usage of generics has \textbf{no implications} for 
        the runtime performance of the compiled programs.
      \item The improved flexibility and type safety means that the 
        compiler has to generate concrete implementation from 
        the generic template for each used type. This means 
        that applications start \textbf{a bit slower}.
      \end{itemize}
      \onslide<2>
      The Java Virtual Machine and the copiled byte code are Generics 
      agnostic. The comiled byte code does not differ from byte code 
      compiled from sources which don't use the generics.
      So using the generics has \textbf{no impact} on the runtime 
      performance of compiled Java code.
    \end{overprint}

  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's interesting ... `onslide<1>{myContent}` gives different results than `onslide<1> myCodntent`.

Comment: This is great!  Exactly what I needed.  There is one major drawback, though: it seems I can no longer use the `handouts` documentclass option if I use an `overprint` environment.  Anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to Paul Gaborit answer, and regarding the comment about Handout, here is what the Beamer User Guide says:

> The overlay specifications of the \onslide commands must be disjoint.
>   This may be a problem for handouts, since, there, all overlay specifications default to 1. If you use the option handout, you can disable all but one \onslide by setting the others to 0.

Example:

```
\begin{overprint}
\onslide<1| handout:1>
Some text for the first slide.\\
Possibly several lines long.
\onslide<2| handout:0>
Replacement on the second slide. Supressed for handout.
\end{overprint}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Quiz}
    \begin{block}{Frage}
        With generics the compiler has more information about the 
        types of the objects, so explicit casts don't have to be used 
        and the compiler can produce type safe code.

        What implications have the generics for the runtime 
        performance of the  program which uses them?
    \end{block}

    \uncover<1>{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item With the generics the compiler can optimize the code for 
              used types\ldots
        \item The usage of generics has \textbf{no implications} for 
              the runtime performance of the compiled programs.
        \item The improved flexibility and type safety means that the 
              compiler has to\ldots
    \end{itemize}}
    \uncover<2>{
        The Java Virtual Machine and the copiled byte code are Generics 
        agnostic. The comiled byte code does not differ from byte code 
        compiled from sources \ldots
    }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems as if I hadn't expressed myself precisely. I'm sorry for that. I want the correct answer to be able to take the space where the possible answers were. I don't want the correct answer to appear below the possible answers.

Comment: Hum, OK, I see understand now. Sorry.

Comment: Example link is dead

Comment: @DragonRock, it is from 2012. I'll remove it.